# doc.data() is not a function error after creating doc and then setting it in firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that querys for a document and returns that document. If I use doc.data() on this it works as expected.

If the query is empty thus the doc doesn't exist it creates the document (this is stored in variable), sets it and then returns the doc.

```js
const snapshot = await db.collection('...').where('name', '==', name)

if (snapshot.empty){
   const doc = await db.collection('...').doc()
   await doc.set({...})
   console.log(doc.data()) /// this crashes
   return doc 
} 
console.log(snapshot.docs[0].data()) // this works fine!!! 
return snaphot.docs[0]
```

I have put in the comments next to the code what crashes and what doesn't. I'm wondering what's going on!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `doc` has the `DocumentReference` and it has no method `data()`. Document data could be retrieved only from the `DocumentSnapshot`, to get this from document reference you have to call the `get()` method.

- `get()` - Reads the document referred to by this DocumentReference.

So try the below snippet,

```js
var doc_snap = await doc.get()
console.log(doc_snap.data())
```

Comment: Thanks alot Muthu! Appreciate it :)